# Octave Install Error on Mac OSX 10.7.5 (using homebrew)

Tags: osx-lion, octave, homebrew

I am trying to install octave on my mac air
I have updated my homebrew, as is my XCode and its command line tools.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
==> Using Homebrew-provided fortran compiler.
This may be changed by setting the FC environment variable.
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/octave/3.6.2 --with-blas=-Wl,-framewo
==> make all
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [liboctave.la] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2

Error: octave did not build
Logs: /Users/uyiewnil/Library/Logs/Homebrew/octave/
Help: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: @itsbruce I'm having the same problem. The log indicates that these .so files have undefined symbols: `.libs/liboctave_la-cmd-edit.o`, `.libs/liboctave_la-cmd-hist.o`, `.libs/liboctave_la-oct-rl-edit.o`, `.libs/liboctave_la-oct-rl-hist.o`